# Parity of a Permutation Significance

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

I have a permutation of `N` numbers.I can perform these operation any number of times in order to sort the permutation.

Choose any 3 consecutive indices and rotate their elements in such a way that `ABC` rotates to `BCA`, which rotates to `CAB`, which rotates back to `ABC`.

**We can sort the numbers only if the number of inversion is odd** i.e odd parity permutation

I don't know how to prove this statement ? How does parity of Permutation decides it can be sorted or not.What is the intuition behind a Parity for a permutation.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the statement of the problem right? The sorted permutation is even, and you can certainly sort it (with zero operations).